# Nested type as function argument

Tags: c++

I have the following template class:

```
template<class T>
class C
{
    typedef C_traits<T>                traits;
    typedef typename traits::some_type type;
    //...
    // use 'traits' and 'type' a lot
    //...
};
```

where `C_traits` is a template struct that has a typedef for `some_type` that is different for each specialization of the type `X`. I am trying to write a function that receives a reference to a variable of `type` as defined above, i.e.:

```
template<class T>
//void f(const C_traits<T>::some_type& c)     <-- this does not work either
void f(const C<T>::type& c)
{
    //...
}
```

I'm getting an "expected unqualified-id before '&' token" error on the line where f is defined. I think I understand why I am getting this error, but I'd like to know if there is any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here.

Put another way, I'd like to do something like this:

```
template<class T>
void f(typename const C<T>::type& c)
{
    //...
}
```

which is not allowed. Any thoughs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T> 
void f(const typename C<T>::type& c) { }
```

This is allowed, but a qualified type is one of the non-deduced contexts.  That is, template argument deduction won't work for this, so you'll have to call the function like so:

```
f(42);      // won't work
f<int>(42); // works
```

If you don't want to supply the type argument explicitly, one option is to have the function just take a `T`:

```
template <typename T> void f(const typename T& c) { }
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Actually, it's `void f(const typename C<T>::type& c)` that worked (the `const` and the `typename` inverted), which is why I claimed that it wasn't allowed.

Comment: Oops, I now realize this is exactly what you said would work. Thanks again.

Comment: @commernie:  No, I had it backwards; I think I must have corrected it just before you posted your comment.  Sorry about that and glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

I got your same error using:

```
template <typename T>
void f(typename const C<T>::type& c) {}
```

but got no error using

```
template <typename T>
void f(const typename C<T>::type& c) {}
```

Comment: Yep. When I tried that before I got a different error (on another line) which was very similar to this one, and this confused me into thinking that did not work. All's good now. Thanks!